# Css scaling issue on mobile

Tags: html, css

im trying to make a website(the first one i ever made) for my girlfriends cat but it looks bad when i open it up on a mobile device. ive tried to change the meta viewpoint but it didnt seem to help.

sorry if my code looks bad its my first time using css

i added the meta tag (`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width  content="width="device-width, initial-scale=1">`) thinking it was a resizing or scaling issue but i dont think it is

Comment: Where is your code? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

#### Original - Wrong

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width  content="width="device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You declared two attributes:

1. content with `"width=device-width  content="` value
2. width with `"device-width, initial-scale=1"` value

#### Solution

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Need only content declared with `"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"` value.

[How to set viewport?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag#viewport_basics)

[Responsive Website](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)